# What to do unused servers

Tags: open-source, distributed-computing

Since I have an application that is growing and i run on hardware I always have a few extra servers sitting around and want to find away to donate them. I am famulaure with folding@Home but maybe there are some less popular projects that could use them. So the question is: What are some open source projects or computing projects that could use these types of resource on an add needed bases? Is there a place I can get a list of these types of communities.

Please keep in mind they are budget machines so they wont be able to find the answier to global hunger 4 or 5:

- Quad AMD dual core 8220
- 32 GB of DDR2 Memory
- 15k 2.5" 500GB SAS HDD
- 20TB  of bandwidth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to contribute to humanity, look into [Folding@Home](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/HomePage) or any of these [distributed computing projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects). Or, if you'd rather make a few cents for yourself, look into [Bitcoin mining](http://www.weusecoins.com/mining-guide.php).

Comment: Since I dont have gpu on these machinces then bitcoin goes out the window. any other projects that can make any money.

Comment: We donate a fair amount of time to world community grid. It's a great way of donating spare CPU cycles.